# Testing Framework for Apps Developed using React Js

Tags: facebook, selenium-webdriver, reactjs, functional-testing, karma-mocha

I am researching about testing framework I can use to test application developed using React JS. So far I have read about JEST and Mocha JS (integrated with Chai JS and Sinon JS) but I am still not able to narrow down what can be used to develop a fully automated testing framework, I know selenium web driver is good for front end testing, is there anything more specific for ReactJS applications?

Comment: All of the tools you've mentioned above can be used to test an React application. It's just a matter of personal preference I would say.

Comment: Are the tools like Jest/Mocha preferred over selenium for testing UI in react based applications?

Comment: You can test React UI to a certain extent using Mocha/Chai or Jest - Selenium, I would say, would be used for maybe automated end-to-end testing.